# How to determine if webpage redirects to certain URL

Tags: php, file-get-contents, redirect

How would I check if `file_get_contents('http://example.com');` redirects me to http://google.com?

Here is the structure of the code:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://example.com');

if(file_redirects_to_http://google.com) {
   echo 'website redirected';
}
```

Comment: You can't detect redirections when you use `file_get_contents`. Use `curl` and see if you get a `Location` header in the response.

Comment: @Barmar I see. It seems like `file_get_contents` is limited to basics. Can you point me to an example of what I need?

Comment: There are many curl tutorials. SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: Not sure because I'm not familiar with it, but you might try using `is_link()`, which is stated to support some url wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
<?php

$curl_output = shell_exec('curl -I --silent "https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl"');

$preg_result = preg_match('/Location:/', $curl_output);

if ($preg_result == 1) {
    echo "Request triggered a redirect\n";
}

// output:
// Request triggered a redirect
```

#### Explanation

I know the URL `https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl` triggers a redirect, so I just send a curl request (command line curl), the `-I` means only show the header of the response.
Then if string `Location` is in the response, assume it was a redirect.

Comment: Thank you. Would I change to `preg_match('/Location:/', $curl_output);` to `preg_match('/Location: http://google.com/', $curl_output);`?

Comment: If you want to detect that the redirection was to that particular URL, sure. the presence of the `Location:` identifier in the header of the response indicates the redirect occurred. If you want to add the `http://google.com/` pattern you would probably need to escape the `/`. i.e. `http:\/\/google.com\/`, but then obviously you will need to test the new regex pattern